# PHP5: SplObjectStorage garbage collection

Tags: php, garbage-collection, spl

I'm using a [SplObjectStorage](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) to keep information about managed objects. When my objects get destructed, I would like the `SplObjectStorage` to automatically cleanup the objects which have no external references anymore.

I can see only two options for this right now:

- having the managed object's destructor inform the storage to remove references to it; this is not acceptable as these objects should not be aware of the manager;
- parsing [debug_zval_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-zval-dump.php) to get the reference count; not acceptable as well, IMHO too "hacky" for a serious application.

Any other ideas?

Comment: There's no magical solution. You will have to make your objects aware of their container. You can't expect objects to collect garbage from something they don't see.

Comment: @netcoder: bad news. I was hoping I'd missed another kind of `SplObjectStorage` that would have built-in support for this!

Comment: The only thing I think you could do other than that is to create your own container implementation, parse objects added to it for composed objects, store their `spl_object_hash` in a map table, and clean the container when a `delete` call is issued. In short, not possible with the default `SplObjectStorage` implementation.

Comment: What do you mean with "clean the container when a `delete` call is issued"? Maybe it's unclear, I need the cleanup to be done automatically on sessions handling a lot of objects!

Comment: @Benjamin Morel: Now that I understand your question, the only two solutions you have are to: modify the SPL extension or create a new extension yourself; or use `debug_zval_dump`. Even your first option won't work, because the object destructor will never be triggered because a reference to the object will still exists in the SplObjectStorage instance.

Comment: True. That would work only if I use `spl_object_hash()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time has gone by & php has evolved, if you are here & are using php **8.2**, there is another option.

You can use a [WeakMap](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.weakmap.php) instead of the [SplObjectStorage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php)

A `WeakMap` is similar to the `splObjectStorage` in the sense that they both use objects as keys.

A WeakMap, however, does not prevent objects that fall out of scope everywhere else from being garbage collected

**For context, here is an `splObjectStorage` example:**

```php
$store = new splObjectStorage();

$object = new stdClass();
$store[$object]  = 'This is my object';

var_dump($store->count()); // int(1)

unset($object);

var_dump($store->count()); // int(1)
```

Note that the `$store` still has the object even if the object was unsset

**...and, here is a `WeakMap` example:**

```php
$store = new WeakMap();

$object = new stdClass();
$store[$object]  = 'This is my object';

var_dump($store->count()); // int(1)

unset($object);

var_dump($store->count()); // int(0)
```

Note that after `unsset`'ing the `$object`, `$store` count is 0

Comment: Yup. Thank you for reviving this old question!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement desired functionality with events. Each managed objects generates an event on destroy and the object manager is subscribed on this event so it will be able to remove a reference to object from the SplObjectStorage.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid, and is a prerequisite in the question: "having the managed object's destructor inform the storage to remove references to it; this is not acceptable as these objects should not be aware of the manager"

Comment: I'm however accepting your answer, as I came to the conclusion that there is just no other way to do that in PHP right now.

Comment: It's common practice in enterprise application to use events, so it's scalable solution.